Segregate identity generator types for different data source in Hibernate 6
We are migrating from Hibernate 5.6 to 6.0, and we use different data sources: PostgreSQL, MS SQL, HSQLDB. And we use Flyway migration with Hibernate schema validation.
Our entities use @Id @GeneratedValue(AUTO).
In Hibernate 5 with hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false  PostgreSQL and MS SQL used autogenerated sequence hibernate_sequence, but HSQLDB used default identity generation (using default keyword in SQL query when inserting, which generated ID on DB side.
Seems like Hibernate 6 changed native AUTO behavior for HSQLDB from IDENTITY to SEQUENCE (like it was with PostgreSQL and MS SQL before0
After migrating to Hibernate 6:

hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings property is dropped by the framework
we applied hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=single which works perfect for PostgreSQL and MSSQL
in Hibernate 6 HSQLDB dialect also expects to generate IDs by the sequence, which does not exist in the schema, so flyway schema validation fails.

But we want to keep the application behavior as it was before, so only PG and MS use sequence, but HSQL uses identity.
How to achieve that?
Is it possible to configure Hibernate so it continues using sequence for PostgreSQL and MS SQL, but for HSQLDB steps back to use previous Identity generator strategy?
Some thoughts, which i'm not sure how to implement:

apply column strategy dynamically, based on table and column name?
define some IdentifierGeneratorFactory or smth similar?
define custom @IdGeneratorType which falls back to IDENTITY or SEQUENCE based on current dataSource type?

What i already tried:
*
@Override
public SequenceSupport getSequenceSupport() {
    return NoSequenceSupport.INSTANCE;
}

Doesn't help, still tries to validate hibernate_sequence
*
@Override
public String getNativeIdentifierGeneratorStrategy() {
    return "identity";
}

Not called at all, as schema validation missing hibernate_sequence fails before calling this value.
